# How to present a UIView from bottom to half of the screen in Swift3 iOS?

Tags: ios, animation, swift3, uiview

I want to move my `UIView`, that I have added to my `Storyboard` from bottom to half of the screen with some animation.

I don't want to present any `UIViewController`, And also don't want to use any `Third party Library`.

I tried to resolve this by setting frame origin y of `UIView` but not achieving. Please suggest me.

Comment: add a bottomConstraint as a IBOutlet and change the constraint constant value inside animation block that's it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a bottomConstraint as a `IBOutlet` and change the constraint constant value inside animation block

[image]

**Full Code**

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var customView: UIView!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 2) {
            self.animate()
        }
    }

    func animate() {
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = 0
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
            self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
        }) { (finished) in

        }
    }

}
```

**Result**
[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response @Reinier, let me apply this code.

Comment: As per your output, UIView is starting from bottom and coming to the super view centre. But according to my requirement It should be like picker, not in center.

Comment: Yes I have seen, let me update this into my code. I will do update you soon. Thanks again..

Comment: @user2786 my answer was updated, your constraint originally should be = -yourCustomView.height and in the animation should change to 0

Comment: Okay and suppose If I need to hide this with animation, then have to set y constraints to -yourCustomView.height?

Comment: Thanks for your time @Reinier :)

Answer (score 0):

Add your view with following constraints

```
leadingConstraint: 0
trailingConstraint: 0
heightConstraint: screenheight/2
botttomConstraint: -height
```

When you want to present your view do following

```
bottomConstraint = 0

UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3) {
    yourView.superview?.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```